# How can I replicate the style of images produced by an old Finepix digital camera?

Tags: post-processing, reverse-engineering, fujifilm, tone-curves

I've got some old photographs taken by a [FujiFilm FinePix S602Z](http://www.dpreview.com/products/fujifilm/compacts/fuji_finepixs602z). I'd love to stylize new photos (taken by a current higher quality camera) to look in the most similar way. What's the correct approach to achieve this?

Notes:

1. Colours: The S602 images have had a specific tint/hue. The sky was a sort of faded turqoise, tree leaves less saturated etc. New photos need to be tone-mapped via a histogram/curve/? in that way. How do I get the correct parameters?
2. Pixel Rendering: [Super CCD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Super_CCD) sensors - thanks to octagonal pixels scanned diagonally - produced specific object edges.
3. Adding some noise and a bit of chromatic aberration is no problem for me.

*Sample [FinePix S602Z photo](http://www.dpreview.com/galleries/reviewsamples/photos/89180/?inAlbum=fuji-finepix-s602z-review-samples) showing the specific sky colour and pixel rendering (see tree leaves at 1:1 in the Original resolution).*

My own unprocessed samples - both native sensor 3.1Mp and camera interpolated 6.3Mp uploaded [here](http://1drv.ms/1K5EEW8). Please use the Download button above to get them in the full resolution.

Answer (score 1):

This is my best I can do at the moment but **I don't accept this answer** as it's only at a halfway to desired results.

Software used: `SilkyPix`; `GIMP 2.8` with `GMIC`, `Focus blur` and `Color` packages.

**Pixel Rendering**

1. Develop the current camera RAW *with no corrections*.
2. Scale the image down to sensor size (2048x1536) with *No Interpolation*.
3. Apply *Focus blur* with the Radius = 0.3 and defaults in other setting
4. Apply *GMIC->Degradations->Noise [additive]*, Amplitude = 6, Channel = Saturation.
5. *Filters->Colors->Chromatic Aberration*, Lateral Blue = +2, Red = +1.
6. Layer->Rotate 45 deg. CW
7. Scale to 2832x2128 target image size with *No Interpolation*
8. Layer->Rotate 45 deg. CCW
9. Flatten Image before further processing
10. Apply Unsharp Mask with Radius = 1.5

**Colours**

1. *Filters->GMIC->Colors->Tone Presets*, Velvetia, Strength = 100
2. *Colors->Hue/Saturation*, Hue = -15, Saturation = -30
3. *Colors->Curves*, clip highlights on the sky a bit

Store to 4:2:2 horizontal JPEG with target size of about 2 MB (quality = 96).

Original (current camera) image (downsized)
[image: Original image (downsized)]

Degraded (stylized) image (downsized)
[image: Degraded image (downsized)]

Degraded (stylized) image rendering detail
[image: Degraded image rendering detail]

Original FinePix S602Z rendering detail
[image: Original FinePix S602Z rendering detail]